# Empty my trash is taking forever

Tags: delete, trash

My ubuntu system has become full
So I analyze the usage and I found a folder (with subfolders) large enough that I don't need.
So I sent them to trash with the "Files" interface. And now to recover the space I want to empty my trash.

Problem is this is taking forever. The file just don't get deleted.
Is there a faster way to empty my trash?

Comment: How large is your folder `.local/share/Trash` ?